# Registrador LR com valor zero no IRQ Interruption handler

Tags: assembly, arm

Configuração do vetor de interrupções:

```
interruption vector:
        b RESET_HANDLER
    .org 0x08
        b SVC_HANDLER
    .org 0x18
        b IRQ_HANDLER
```

Na primeira linha da rotina `IRQ_HANDLER`, o valor do registador `LR` (visto com auxílio do GDB) é `0`.

Como consequência, no final da rotina `subs pc, lr, #4` o resultado é um erro do tipo `Segmentation Fault`.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 1):

A rotina `subs pc, lr, #4` seta para o registrador `PC` o valor do registrador `LR` (que como mencionado é zero) menos o imediato `#4` ou seja, no próximo ciclo o processador deve resumir a execução a partir de `LR - 4` que é um endereço inválido, por isso o `SEGFAULT`.

Os passos a serem tomados para habilitar seguramente interrupções `IRQ` descritos na [documentação ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0203j/Cacbhjjj.html) são:

1. Construir o endereço de retorno e salvá-lo na pilha do modo `IRQ`.
2. Salvar os registradores necessários e o `SPSR` do modo `IRQ`.
3. Identificar e limpar a fonte da interrupção.
4. Mudar para o modo `System` mantendo as `IRQ`s desabilitadas.
5. Checar se a pilha está alinhada a oito bytes e ajustar se necessário.
6. Salvar o `LR` do modo `User` e o ajuste, `0` ou `4` para `ARMv4` ou `ARMv5TE`, usado no `SP` do modo `User`.
7. Habilitar interrupções e chamar a função tratadora de interrupção.
8. Quando a função tratadora retornar, desabilitar interrupções.
9. Restaurar o `LR` do modo `User` e o valor de ajuste da pilha.
10. Reajustar a pilha caso necessário.
11. Mudar para o modo `IRQ`.
12. Restaurar os outros registradores e o `SPSR` do modo `IRQ`.
13. Retornar do `IRQ`.

Resumindo: certifique-se de estar usando o valor de `LR` no modo certo e de que não está o sobrescrevendo em nenhum lugar.

Importante: O retorno de uma interrupção é **diferente** do retorno de uma função pois o `PC` guarda o endereço da próxima instrução a ser executada e numa exceção/interrupção o valor de `PC` é copiado para `LR_<mode>` então se você saltasse para esse valor a instrução referenciada por este endereço nunca seria executada, por isso que é  a subtração (`LR - 4`).